# How to require admin permissions to stop an executable in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, security, permissions

I have an executable on a Windows 8 machine, that I’d like to keep running. The problem is, the guy I share my dorm room and the Windows 8 machine with keeps shutting it off.

Is there a way (application, script, or settings solution) to require admin permissions to kill a program?

I'm thinking there has to be some kind of watchdog application to do this, and in order to kill the watchdog process, you must have admin permissions.

Also, yes, I have asked him not to. Still, he continues believing that turning off my game server is funny.

**Edit:**

I mean a watchdog *on* my windows 8 machine to restart the server when it is terminated or crashes. The problem, is I can't find any watchdogs that you must be administrator to shut down.

Comment: do you mean a watchdog application that runs on the server, or a watchdog application that you can run from another machine to monitor whether the server is up or not?

Comment: I don’t understand the problem. Do you and your roommate share an account? Does your roommate know the password to your account? Do you leave the PC unlocked, logged in as you? Does your program have an interface that allows arbitrary users (other than the one who started it) to tell it to exit? Is he shutting off your program by rebooting the machine?

Comment: your server hogging the bandwidth/memory/cpu? that is the problem, not him turning it off. Share the room, and don't forget to share the bandwith too...